# How do I know which xib is the first one to load?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I am researching a huge Xcode project, how do I know which xib is the first xib be loaded by IOS?

In main.m, I can only know the main delegation file, but how to find the main.xib.

BTW, I search the {project}-info.plist, but found nothing.

Addtion, I know which file is the rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

From your description the project doesn't use storyboard(s), so the initial window and root view controller are created by the app delegate. This may or may not use an XIB file (you'd need to check the implementation if the view controller class).